# Files in RPM packages

Tags: package-management, rpm

There is something strange with RPM packages. The listed contents, enumerated by `rpm -ql` differ from the actually presented files. For instance, I downloaded a `openldap-servers-2.4.26-8.fc16.i686.rpm` and ran the one-liner:

```
rpmfile=openldap-servers-2.4.26-8.fc16.i686.rpm; diff <(rpm2cpio $rpmfile | cpio -t | sed -e 's!^\.!!g') <(rpm -ql -p $rpmfile)
```

It compares the contents of the `rpm` unpacked by `rpm2cpio` with output from `rpm -ql`

And got:

```
9122 blocks
20a21,22
> /etc/openldap/slapd.conf
> /etc/openldap/slapd.conf.bak
21a24
> /etc/pki/tls/certs/slapd.pem
```

`rpm -ql` states that there are 3 files in the package which actually are absent.
Is there an explanation for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPM packages are built using a `.spec` file that contains various sections that tell `rpm` what to do as it installs your package.  The files that you are seeing are most likely being created on the fly by `rpm` as it installs the `openldap` package.  The `rpm -ql` command is actually reading the `.spec` file and telling you exactly what will be installed, while the `cpio` command is just dumping a list of files that are archived in the `.rpm`.  If you're really curious you can download `openldap-2.4.26-8.fc16.src.rpm`, install it and look at the `.spec` file for yourself, it's pretty straight forward to read.  Careful building though, an incorrect path combined with running `rpmbuild` as root can really ruin your day.

Comment: Thank you. I have already examine source package and post install scripts. You are right. It is "temp" files for creatig initial slapd.d config.